# Informal phrase for finally doing something pending - very specific

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

What would be an informal saying of phrase for finally doing some chore or running some errand that was pending for some time?

It maybe something you are avoiding, or something you forget all the time only to remember it when you no longer are in the place wher it can be done. Every time you think of it you sigh in disapproval of yourself. One day finally you do it on an impulse and you get done with it.

You may say, in relief, *"I finally crossed that off my list"* but in a more informal, idiomatic way.

*"To get something over and done with"* means *"to do something difficult or unpleasant as soon as you can"* and does not convey the fact the thing was pending to be done for some time, on the opposite, you did it at the very first opportunity to had to not have to worry about it later. Also The phrase I'm looking for doesn't necessarily refer to something difficult or unpleasant.

Comment: _stopped procrastinating_ comes to mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"***I finally got that monkey off my back***" is a common, colorful idiom that applies if the task in question was nagging at you. It likely doesn't apply if you merely forgot about it for a long time until now; it can't be a monkey on your back if you don't notice it at all.  But monkeys on your back are there for a long time, by their nature.  The task need not be unpleasant to be a monkey, but it must be an obligation, something that you are *required* to do.

Answer (score 3):

Even if *finally* isn't explicitly specified, it's usually implied by...

> *"I [finally] **got around to** [doing some long-overdue task]"*.
>
> [**get around/round to something**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-around-to)
>   *to do something **after you have intended to do it for some time***

Answer (score 1):

**I finally got around to doing it** implies that you could have done it at any time; you just didn't bother to until just recently.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most succinct phrase but it is idiomatic:

***I've stopped putting off the inevitable*** (and got it done).